# MongoDB does not seem to behave how it should as a whole

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, express, database

When I first used MongoDB I managed to connect successfully, however then I wanted to carry out the most basic query such as:

```
db.users.find()
```

I got an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`
Basically meaning I cannot use a collection as a property to the object db.

So i tried this:

```
var user_col = db.collection('users');
user.col.find();
```

which works absolutely fine.

Over the last few days I have kept having to look up other ways of doing things as the standard documented way doesn't seem to work. Just now I wanted to get the total users on the app, so like it says in the documentation I should do this:

```
var count = db.runCommand( { count: 'users' } );
console.log(count);
```

however this gave the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Is there a problem with MongoDB you have seen like this before or am I just being stupid? I do not want to have to keep finding other, less efficient ways of doing things so finally I ask here what is going on.

Thank you.

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: I think you might be confusing the [Mongo shell API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/) with the [node.js native driver API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html).  While both are JavaScript, the shell is sync while node.js is async so they're totally different.

Comment: Yes, that looks like thats what I'm getting confused about. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are confusing the [Mongo shell API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/) with the [node.js native driver API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html). While both are JavaScript, the shell is sync while node.js is async so they're totally different.